# No custom time bar found with id undefined - Vis js (while updating to the current version)

Tags: javascript, jquery, vis.js, vis.js-network, vis.js-timeline

I updated vis.js plugin from 3.10.0 to 4.20.1. Many methods are deprecated in new version. I fixed all of them. At last I'm strucked on this issue.

> ***Error: No custom time bar found with id undefined***

```
var container = document.getElementById('visualization');

var maxzoom = 7*24*60*60*1000;
var options = {
    start : new Date(1950, 1, 10),
    end: new Date(2020, 10, 10), 
    min: new Date(1950, 1, 10),
    max: new Date(2020, 10, 10),
    zoomMin: maxzoom,
    showCurrentTime: true,
    width: "100%",
    editable: false,
    zoomable: true,
    orientation: 'top',
    align: 'center',
    margin: {
        axis: 1,
        item: {
            horizontal: 1,
            vertical: 1
        }
    }
};

var groups = new vis.DataSet([
{ id: 0, content: 'A1' },
{ id: 1, content: 'A2' },
{ id: 2, content: 'A3' },
{ id: 3, content: 'A4<br>Other' }]);

var items = new vis.DataSet([]);
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options, groups);

timeline.setCustomTime("1958-07-06");
```

> After a long search I found this one causing an issue.

```
> timeline.setCustomTime("1958-07-06");
```

How can I pass id in **setCustomTime**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should addCustomTime to add element first,like this

let customBar = document.querySelector( '.customDateBar' );
customBar === null ? timeline.addCustomTime( time, 'customDateBar' ) : timeline.setCustomTime( time, 'customDateBar' );

.customDateBar is your ID